# Previous tab components are visible on parsing the json datas - cn1

Tags: codenameone

There are a couple of tabs in a screen. Each tab with its own connectionRequest. But when any tab is selected, the components of the previous tab flashes before new tab components are seen. How can I solve this. Using addShowListener in each tab has its own issue. It shows blank screen. 
Please have a look at the video [here](https://youtu.be/w6lW1WqwasI)

Here if you go from home tab to service tab, service tab components are seen and it starts to parse the json data(loader is seen). Then the components from home screen is seen before the parsed data is shown in service tab component.

```
Tabs tabs = new Tabs(Component.BOTTOM);
tabs.addTab("Home", calendarIcon, homeContainer);
tabs.addTab("Book", calendarIcon3, quickBookingContainer);
tabs.addTab("Servicing", calendarIcon1, servicingContainer);
tabs.addTab("History", calendarIcon2, serviceHistoryContainer);

add(BorderLayout.CENTER, tabs);

tabs.addSelectionListener((int oldSelected, int newSelected) -> {
    if (newSelected == 0) {
        //connectionRequest for parsing json data
        homeContainerRequest(homeContainer, res);
    } else if (newSelected == 1) {
        quickBookingContainerRequest(quickBookingContainer, res);
    } else if (newSelected == 2) {
        serviceRequest(serviceContainer, res);
    } else if (newSelected == 3) {
        serviceHistoryRequest(serviceHistoryContainer, res);
    } 
});


public void homeContainerRequest(Container homeContainer, Resources res){
    ConnectionRequest con = new ConnectionRequest(url, false) {

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
            Map parser = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
        }
    };
    con.setFailSilently(true);
    con.addRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(con);
}

public void quickBookingContainerRequest(Container quickBookingContainer, Resources res){
    ConnectionRequest con = new ConnectionRequest(url1, false) {

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
            Map parser = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
        }
    };
    con.setFailSilently(true);
    con.addRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(con);
}

public void serviceHistoryRequest(Container serviceHistoryContainer, Resources res){
    ConnectionRequest con = new ConnectionRequest(url2, false) {

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
            Map parser = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
        }
    };
    con.setFailSilently(true);
    con.addRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(con);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it relates to the animation and excessive repaint calls. Try using `tabs.setAnimateTabSelection(false)`.

Comment: If we use addShowListener in a form, it immediately goes to that form and does the parsing etc. How to get that done in tabs? Now what happens is the connectionRequest runs (the previous tab is shown at the moment), after the connection is successful, it goes to the selected tab.

Comment: If you disable the animation you can just use `callSerially` to wrap the event and the tab will be shown before the method.